# Scribus has no Spell check

Tags: spell-checking, scribus

There is no spell check in Scribus 1.4.0 and 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. Also tried installing aspell still no spell check. It does not appear at the end of the item menu.

How do you get Scribus to recognize the spelling libraries? Is it compiled wrong and so do I have to recompile it?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing hunspell and hunspell engines as per choice of your language.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Scribus 1.4.2: http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Debian There is Hunspell.